# DHTMLX JavaPlanner maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, dhtmlx

Is there any maven dependency for  DHTMLX  javaCalendar and/or  DHTMLX  JavaPlanner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

There are 2 cases that you need to issue Maven’s command to include a jar into the Maven local repository manually.

```
1.The jar you want to use doesn’t exist in the Maven center repository.
2.You created a custom jar, and need to use for another Maven project.
```

Please Check the link.
mkyong
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Thanks mkyong.

Comment: Could you please share the link from where you get the javaplanner dependency. I tried fire getting the same. But not able to find the jar. Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans:

1.Add maven dependency in you pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dhtmlx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaplanner</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.Clean Build your project

3.You will see warning sign in your javaplanner1.5 in your maven dependencies list.

4.Right Click and select 'Manually Install Artifact' and select the downloaded jar file.

5.Select 'install locally' and you are done.