# Maven dependency for javaplanner not resolving

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I have a dependency for javaplanner in my project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javaplanner</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaplanner</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am having an issue when building the project, giving error not able to resolve the dependency:

```
Failure to find javaplanner:javaplanner:jar:1.5
in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
elapsed or updates are forced
-> [Help 1]
```

I tried to search the javaplanner dependency in the mvn repository, but its missing there.

How can I resolve this issue? Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Have you tried deleting your .m2 folder and then rebuilding the project?

Comment: No I didnt try that. Why we need to delete the m2 folder? The issue is not able to find the corresponding dependency right?

Answer (score 1):

`javaplanner` does not exist in Maven Central and does not appear to exist in any other public Maven repository. It has also been discontinued and is no longer downloadable from its provider if it is as I suspect "DHTMLX JavaPlanner" - see https://dhtmlx.com/blog/javaplanner-full-featured-scheduler-for-java/.

To resolve this issue you'll need to download the dependency's JAR file from a third-party site, verify that the downloaded JAR is what used to be available from dhtmlx.com and install the JAR as the `javaplanner:javaplanner` dependency in your local (or private shared - e.g. Nexus, Artifactory, JFrog - see https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) Maven repository. See [DHTMLX JavaPlanner maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20745666/1840078) for more on the local install process.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I tried to get the dependency for the javaplanner:javaplanner from https://mvnrepository.com, but not getting the same.
I have tried the dependency :
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dhtmlx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaplanner</artifactId>

        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
Its also getting the same error

Comment: The dependency is not in Maven  or mvnrepository.com. https://dhtmlx.com/blog/javaplanner-full-featured-scheduler-for-java/ from March 2013 states "DHTMLX JavaPlanner had spent a long and happy life, but now its support and development is discontinued, the website and the library won’t be available anymore." The library appears to be still hosted on various download sites... but the usual caveats about downloading binaries from non-authoritative sites apply: check the checksums if available, scan for viruses, et cetera.

Comment: Hi @Mark A. Fitzgerald, Could you please provide a link to download the javaplanner dependency? I have searched a lot and didnt able to find one.

Comment: I see - attempts to download from both https://dhtmlx-javaplanner.soft112.com/ and https://dhtmlx-javaplanner.soft32.com/ end up at http://www1.javaplanner.com/?kw=java%20planner&KW1=Monthly%20Weekly%20Planner which does not host the JAR. A legitimate looking copy of the GPL version of the product is presently downloadable from https://www.download3k.com/DownloadLink1-DHTMLX-JavaPlanner.html (US) and https://www.download3k.com/DownloadLink2-DHTMLX-JavaPlanner.html (EU) at https://www.download3k.com/Install-DHTMLX-JavaPlanner.html.